# Show touch when clicked UIButton Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIButton that has only an UIImage set, when Clicked (long press) the images changes automatically with a shadow, What I want is that even if the button gets clicked but not with a long press the images should have the shadow. I already tried from IB to set the UIButton properties `Reverse on Highlight` and `Shows Touch On Highlight` but with no results

Comment: You should show what have you tried with code?

Answer (score 0):

This is about [UIControl Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/). It's default to be with shadow. So if you wanna customize it, you should `addTarget` to your button to every action on `UIButton` like `tapping`,`long press`,`touchUpInside` and I think it s not about long press it's just you can't realize the difference on tapping.

in one of my project I customize my button actions like this:

```
buyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*3/4-2, 0, self.frame.size.width/4+4, self.frame.size.height)];
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonNormal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonNormal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

and methods of this like:

```
- (void) buyButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
    if ([self.backgroundColor isEqual:[Util UIColorForHexColor:@"fede32"]]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [Util UIColorForHexColor:@"fdca2e"];
}
    else if([self.backgroundColor isEqual:[Util UIColorForHexColor:@"cfd3dc"]]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [Util UIColorForHexColor:@"c0c5d0"];
}
```

}

```
- (void) buyButtonNormal:(UIButton *) sender  {
    if ([self.backgroundColor isEqual:[Util UIColorForHexColor:@"fdca2e"]]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [Util UIColorForHexColor:@"fede32"];
}
    else if([self.backgroundColor isEqual:[Util UIColorForHexColor:@"c0c5d0"]]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [Util UIColorForHexColor:@"cfd3dc"];
}
[delegate purchaseOffer:selectedOffer];
```

}

If you need more information about `UIButton` actions there are a lot of question on this site.